# how to make the fist static tab on 2nd menu tabs selected what ever user select from first tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tabs, angular-ui

I have 2 tabs menus first one created dynamically and the second one first tab is static and other are dynamically created using ng repeat my quetion is how to make the fist static tab on 2nd menu tabs selected what ever user select from first tabs? I use setting  active  but still not  working right

html

```
            <tabset>
                <tab ng-repeat="tab in countytabs" heading="{{tab.countyName}}" select="selectAllUserByCounty(tab.countyID)">
                    <h3>{{tab.countyName}}--{{tab.phoneNumber}} </h3>
                    <tabset>
                        <tab heading="All" active="active.all" select="selectAllUserByCounty(tab.countyID)">
                            <br />
                            <span>Total:{{totalStatusforByCounty.total}}, In:{{totalStatusforByCounty.in}}, Out:{{totalStatusforByCounty.out}}, Unknown: {{totalStatusforByCounty.unknown}} at {{totalStatusforByCounty.lastUpdatedDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}} </span>
                            <br />
                            <div ng-repeat="groupUsers in allUserByCounty">
                                <h6>
                                    <b>{{groupUsers.title}}</b>
                                </h6>
                                <table ng-repeat="user in groupUsers.users">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} Ext:{{user.voiceMailExt}} </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </tab>
                        <tab ng-repeat="departmentGroup in departmentGroups" heading="{{departmentGroup.name}}" select="selectAllUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(tab.countyID,departmentGroup.id)">
                            {{departmentGroup.name}}<br />
                            {{tab.countyID}}<br />
                            {{departmentGroup.id}}<br />

                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <span>
                                        Total:{{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.total}}, In:{{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.in}}, Out:{{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.out}}, Unknown: {{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.unknown}} at {{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.lastUpdatedDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div ng-repeat="groupUsers in allUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup">
                                <h6>
                                    <b>{{groupUsers.title}}</b>
                                </h6>
                                <table ng-repeat="user in groupUsers.users">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} Ext:{{user.voiceMailExt}} </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </tab>
                    </tabset>
                </tab>
            </tabset>
        </div>
```

my controller

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('usersboard');

    var ReceptionController = function($scope, ReceptionService){

        $scope.countytabs = '';
        $scope.totalStatusforAllCounties ='';
        $scope.totalStatusforByCounty = '';
        $scope.departmentGroups = '';
        $scope.totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = '';
        $scope.allUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = '';
        $scope.allUserByCounty = '';
        $scope.AllUserInAllDepartmentGroupsGroupByCounties = '';
        $scope.AllUsersInDepartmentGroup= '';
        $scope.active = {
            all: false
        };
        $scope.content = 'county';
        $scope.isShown = function (content) {
            return content === $scope.content;
        };

        var selectAllCounties = function(){
            ReceptionService.selectAllCounties().then(function(data){
                $scope.countytabs = data;

            }, function(errMsg){
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        selectAllCounties();

        var selectTotalStatusforAllCounties = function(){
            ReceptionService.selectTotalStatusforAllCounties().then(function(data){
                $scope.totalStatusforAllCounties = data;
                console.log(data);
            }, function(errMsg){
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        selectTotalStatusforAllCounties();

        var selectAllDepartmentGroups = function(){
            ReceptionService.selectAllDepartmentGroups().then(function (data) {
                $scope.departmentGroups = data;
                console.log(data);
            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        selectAllDepartmentGroups();

        $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty = function (id) {
            if (typeof id !== 'undefined'){
                ReceptionService.selectTotalStatusforByCounty(id).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.totalStatusforByCounty = data;
                    console.log($scope.totalStatusforByCounty);
                }, function (errMsg) {
                    console.log(errMsg);
                });
            }

        }
        $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = function (countyId, departmentGroup) {
            ReceptionService.selectTotalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(countyId, departmentGroup).then(function (data) {
                $scope.totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = data;
                console.log($scope.totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup);
            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        $scope.selectAllUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = function (countyId, departmentGroup){
            $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(countyId, departmentGroup);
            ReceptionService.selectAllUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(countyId, departmentGroup).then(function (data) {
                $scope.allUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = data;

            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        $scope.selectAllUserByCounty = function (countyId) {

                $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty(countyId);
                ReceptionService.selectAllUserByCounty(countyId).then(function(data){
                    $scope.allUserByCounty = data;


                }, function(errMsg){
                    console.log(errMsg);
                });

        }

        $scope.selectAllUserInAllDepartmentGroups = function () {

            ReceptionService.selectAllUserInAllDepartmentGroups().then(function (data) {
                $scope.AllUserInAllDepartmentGroupsGroupByCounties = data;

            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        $scope.selectAllUsersInDepartmentGroups = function (departmentGroupId) {

            ReceptionService.selectAllUsersInDepartmentGroup(departmentGroupId).then(function (data) {
                $scope.AllUsersInDepartmentGroup = data;

            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }


    };

    app.controller('ReceptionController', ['$scope', 'ReceptionService', '$window', ReceptionController]);

}());
```

Comment: Side note - your HTML and controller code seems really big. It should probably be broken up into directives.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I know my HTML so big but it is prototype for now I will break it up soon I get the concept done

Comment: That is a bad decision. Learn how to use directives and use them from the start. It pays off dividends in the not so long run.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr/fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the parent tab is clicked, set a variable (in my example, `tab.activate1`) to true.  Then, use that value to activate first child tab:

```
<tabset>
<tab ng-repeat="tab in countytabs" ng-click="tab.activate1 = true" heading="{{tab.countyName}}">
  <h3>{{tab.countyName}}--{{tab.phoneNumber}} </h3>
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="All" active="tab.activate1"></tab>
    <tab heading="Detail 1"></tab>
    <tab heading="Detail 2"></tab>
  </tabset>
</tab>
</tabset>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wcs2hdVtem5b2gzbCy5L?p=preview